# CASE still returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, case

Trying to get the output in Dx_3 to print `''` if it is `NULL` but everything I have tried (`NULLIF()`, `COALESCE()`, `ELSE ''`, etc) still prints a `NULL`.

```
SELECT
    @RecordType AS RecordType_1
    ,AbstractData.AccountNumber AS AcctNum_2
    ,(SELECT
            CASE 
                    WHEN AD.Diagnosis IS NOT NULL THEN AD.Diagnosis
                    ELSE ''
            END
            FROM AbsDrgDiagnoses AD 
            WHERE (AD.DiagnosisSeqID ='1' AND AD.VisitID = AbstractData.VisitID)) AS Dx_3
FROM AbstractData --214
WHERE AbstractData.PtStatus <> 'REF'
```

Comment: Try this `Coalesce(...., '') AS Dx_3`

Comment: I suggest the above for handling cases where there is no match in the subquery. If there is no match in the subquery it will return null and that final result is what you need to coalesce. Doing the coalesce within the subquery would not help in those circumstances.

Comment: Removing the lines between the parenthesis and inserting COALESCE(AD.Diagnosis,'') AS Dx_3 does work, but it also returns all dx's associated with the account where the code between the parenthesis limits it to only 1.

Comment: Um, that wasn't what I was suggesting. The `....` are your existing subquery.

Comment: Another thought, might it make more sense to do a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a subquery?

Comment: I did that but it returns each dx for each account. Duh... I added AND AbsDrgDiagnoses.DiagnosisSeqID ='1' to the left join and it worked.. Thanks Jer!

Comment: Ok so why was it returning the NULL in the case but not showing it outside of it? Is it because it was in a sub query? If that is the case why would the sub query pull a null and skip the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT @RecordType AS RecordType_1,
       AbstractData.AccountNumber AS AcctNum_2,
       COALESCE(AD.Diagnosis, '') AS Dx_3
FROM AbstractData
LEFT JOIN AbsDrgDiagnoses AD ON AD.VisitID = AbstractData.VisitID
WHERE AbstractData.PtStatus <> 'REF' AND AD.DiagnosisSeqID = '1'
```

Comment: Don't know why the heck I didn't think of using the AND AD.DiagnosisSeqID = '1' in the LEFT JOIN.... Thank you for your answer.